# How is working insertOnDuplicate() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

Who can help me and explain how work insertOnDuplicate in magento 2. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of insertOnDuplicate query using Magento 2,  You need to create a Connection object first to run the query using ResourceConnection class.

When you insert any new row into a table if the row causes a duplicate in Primary key or UNIQUE index, throw an error in MySQL.

**Base Definition of function is :**

```
/**
 * Inserts a table row with specified data.
 *
 * @param mixed $table The table to insert data into.
 * @param array $data Column-value pairs or array of column-value pairs.
 * @param array $fields update fields pairs or values
 * @return int The number of affected rows.
 */
public function insertOnDuplicate($table, array $data, array $fields = []);
```

**Example :**

```
<?php
class Magento2Sql
{
 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
 ) {
     $this->resource = $resource;
 }

 public function executeInsertOnDuplicate()
 {
     $tableName = "Your_Tablename";
     $data = ["column_name1"=>"value1","column_name2"=>"value2"]; // Key_Value Pair
     $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
     $connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $data);
 }
}
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018868/insertonduplicate-isnt-working-in-magento